# Make expressions equal to 1,000 using exactly six 1s

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

- You may use up to two subtraction symbols (no negation symbols).
- You may use up to two decimal points.
- You will use one vinculum for division (no "/").
- You may use concatenation of digits only, including forming numbers which have decimal points in them.
- You may not use grouping symbols such as parentheses, brackets, or braces.
- You may not use factorial signs.
- You may not use square roots.
- You may not use exponentiation.
- You may not use logarithms.
- You may not use trigonometric functions.
- You may not use any other characters or operations.
- This is in base 10.  (The numbers using the ones, and 1,000 on the other side of the
  equals sign, are in base 10.)

*Try to create six different solutions.*

Comment: To clarify are you allowed to use any 0's or exclusively the six 1's and decimals?

Comment: @gabbo1092 -- No zeroes may be used.  You can write .1, 1.1, .11, 1.11, etc., if they would make expressions have the correct value(s).

Comment: bin-->dec(1111101000)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution 1

> $\frac{111-11}{.1}$

Solution 2

> $\frac{111}{.111}$

Solution 3

> $\frac{1}{.111-.11}$

Solution 4

> $\frac{11}{.111-.1}$

Solution 5

> $\frac{11-1}{.11-.1}$

Solution 6

> $\frac{111-1}{.11}$

Comment: 1) I would not consider the negative signs you used in solutions 2 and 4 to be subtraction symbols.  2) Along with the first point, and adding in solution 6, solutions 2, 4, and 6 are not of "six different solutions" in the spirit of the forms A/B = -A/(-B).

Comment: @ hexomino -- Attention!  Your solutions 3 and 4 equal -1,000.

Comment: @OliveStemforn Apologies on 3 and 4, edited now. Sorry, also, my understanding of "subtraction symbol" was that negation was okay, my mistake.

Comment: hexomino, you have essentially three different solutions out of the six different solutions in your solutions 1, 3, and 5.  There are still three other solutions significantly different from those that I am looking for from any contributor(s).

Comment: @OliveStemforn I've replaced 2, 4 and 6 now with something essentially different

Comment: hexomino, your solutions are thorough.  The problem is solved.